# How to solve java.io.IOException: No such file or directory or Permission denied issue on executing sh file from android in windows machine

Tags: android, permission-denied

I need to execute an sh file using commandline option from the android program. I tried using Runtime.getRuntime().exec. I tried to pass the command as string as well as string[]. But still the issue exists. I have already given permission for read and write in external storage in manifest file.

I tried by using the paths such as

1. getContext().getFilesDir() +
2. "/data/user/0//files/..."
3. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
4. path in our system such as C:\Users\...

I tried using cp, rm, ls....and the commands that I needed actually..
For all the above trials, IO Exception occurred. (Either Permission denied or No such file or directory)

Could you know a possible solution to get out of this error and execute the sh file using command line in android program.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where is your .sh file resided?

Comment: I tried after placing it in res/rew folder. Also I tried after placing it in getContext().getFilesDir()+... and used it